# LinqToSql is trying to insert a foreign key child when it already exists over WCF. What can I do?

Tags: .net, wcf, linq-to-sql, foreign-keys

I'm having trouble inserting a new LinqToSql object over WCF.

What I'm doing is just sending an Orders Batch to the service. Inside the batch are Orders that have already been sent previously. When I do

```
data.batches.InsertOnSubmit(newbatch)
```

I get a SQL error:

```
"Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_HTOrder'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.HTOrder'. The statement has been terminated."
```

Here's the code where it inserts the batch (obj):

```
Dim tableproperty As PropertyInfo = dataProperties.Find(Function(p As PropertyInfo) (p.PropertyType.FullName.Contains("[" + obj.GetType.FullName + ",")))
Dim tableMethod As MethodInfo = tableproperty.GetGetMethod()
Dim tab As Object = tableMethod.Invoke(data, New Object() {})

tab.GetType.GetMethod("InsertOnSubmit", New Type() {obj.GetType}).Invoke(tab, New Object() {obj})
data.SubmitChanges(ConflictMode.FailOnFirstConflict)

Dim checkMatch As Object = GetMatchingEntities(obj, data).SingleOrDefault
If checkMatch Is Nothing Then Throw New UpdateNotVerfiedExecption(obj)
Return checkMatch
```

I've tried attaching the parent to the context first, but it naturally told me it existed when I tried to Insert it right after. Attaching the child orders doesn't seem to help either.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Well, basically, for each order that you receive over the WCF service in your batch, you'd have to check first whether or not it exists already. If it does, you shouldn't call `InsertOnSubmit` on it - since it's in the database already. You can't just insert the whole batch if elements in it are already in the database.

Something like:

```
foreach(Order order in newbatch)
{
   if(data.Orders.Any(o => o.OrderID = order.ID))
   {
     // order already exists - update it
     data.Orders.Attach(order);
   }
   else
   { 
     // order does not exist already --> insert it
     data.Orders.InsertOnSubmit(order);
   }
}
```

When an order is new and doesn't exist yet -> insert it using `InsertOnSubmit`. If it already exists, re-attach it to the data context and thus provide Linq-To-SQL a change to do its change tracking and update the row.

After all this, of course, you need to call `SubmitChanges()` on the context to make all these changes and inserts stick!

Marc